# Python, heapq: difference between heappushpop() and peeking/popping

Tags: python, heap, heapq

Is there a significant difference in functionality and/or efficiency between using `heappushpop` and peeking at the heap first then deciding whether to pop (using `heapreplace`)?

E.g.

```
from heapq import *
a = [5, 18, 9, 14, 22]
heapify(a) # a = [5, 14, 9, 18, 22]
heappushpop(a, 7) # Returns 5 and a = [7, 14, 9, 18, 22]
heappushpop(a, 2) # Returns 2 and a = [7, 14, 9, 18, 22]
```

```
from heapq import *
def customPop(heap, val):
    if heap and heap[0] >= val:
        return val
    
    return heapreplace(heap, val)
    
a = [5, 18, 9, 14, 22] 
heapify(a) # a = [5, 14, 9, 18, 22]
customPop(a, 7) # Returns 5 and a = [7, 14, 9, 18, 22]
customPop(a, 2) # Returns 2 and a = [7, 14, 9, 18, 22]
```

Comment: You do know that you have the source code for `heapq` on your system, right?  `heappushpop` is essentially implemented like your `customPop` function.

Answer (score 0):

The custom method appears to be about 1.5 times slower.

Benchmarked with ipython and python 3.10.3 with:

```py
%%timeit
a = [5, 18, 9, 14, 22]
heapify(a)
<statement>
```

| statement | `%%timeit` |
| --- | --- |
| `heappushpop(a, 7)` | 365 ns ± 3.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) |
| `heappushpop(a, 2)` | 326 ns ± 3.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) |
| `customPop(a, 7)` | 539 ns ± 7.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) |
| `customPop(a, 2)` | 475 ns ± 27.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) |